# Flink-1.4.2 Getting Error: object contrib is not a member of package org.apache.flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am using `flink-1.4.2` and trying to use `RocksDBStateBackend`. While importing `org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend`.

I am getting this error:

> contrib is not a member of package org.apache.flink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information I only guess you haven't included the RocksDb dependency in your pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using build.sbt.

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-statebackend-rocksdb" % "1.4.0" % Test

Comment: I have added this library depency

Comment: You can get an example project built with sbt and using rocksdb https://github.com/soniclavier/bigdata-notebook/blob/master/flink/build.sbt

Comment: Hi Ezequiel, Thanks for helping me. It is working for me.